# Declaring member variable and type at runtime

Tags: c++, templates, shared-ptr, unordered-map, multimap

The following is in reference to a question I asked yesterday that got a great response but which brought up a whole new problem / misunderstanding for me. To see the previous post see [constructing templated containers that are themselves shared_ptr types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50006137/constructing-templated-containers-that-are-themselves-shared-ptr-types).

Here is the reference code:

```
template <class T>
struct A {
    int id;
    T x;
}

template<typename T>
using A_ptr = std::shared_ptr<A<T>>;

template<typename T>
using AMap = std::unordered_map<int , A_ptr<T>>;
```

This works great, but the the problem I found it that it doesn't actually solve my problem.

I have a class with 3 members. The first 2 are each a multimap, but one is sorted in descending order while the other is sorted in ascending order. I also have an unordered map which stores struct A as values. In the case of the A struct, T x ends up being an iterator to one or the other multimaps. I don't know which until runtime. If I structure my code as follows, it won't compile.

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<B_Type> B_Type_ptr;

template <class T>
struct A {
    B_Type_ptr b_ptr;
    T x;
}

template<typename T>
using A_ptr = std::shared_ptr<A<T>>;

template<typename T>
using AMap = std::unordered_map<int , A_ptr<T>>;

class MyClass {
private:
    AMap my_A_map;
    std::multimap<int, B_Type_ptr> my_C_1_map;
    std::multimap<int, B_Type_ptr, greater<int>> my_C_2_map;

}
```

Essentially, I need to require AMap hold a series of A's each of which has x members that are either an ascending type or descending type iterator which will be known at runtime. As I understand, templates are compile time constructs, so how do I get around this without having to resort to A storing information for both an ascending or descending iterator?

Please let me know if the information I have provided is insufficient to solve the problem. I have tried to balance what's necessary to what's overkill. Thanks.

Comment: Is this your real code?  The compiler should be pointing out that you're missing semicolons.  And you haven't defined `B_Type`.

Comment: Templates are resolved entirely at compile time, they can't be dependent on anything that is determined at runtime.

Comment: An intended use case could be useful.

Comment: You are likely structuring this wrong if you want to store iterators to other maps. If you're hell-bent, though, you could use a type that can represent both iterators at runtime, like [std::variant](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant).

Comment: Eg: https://godbolt.org/g/a4PhLf

Comment: std::iterator might work too: https://godbolt.org/g/oZdPZZ

Comment: Thanks Daniel! I agree, l’m likely structuring it wrong. However, I’m still learning c++ and this seemed to be a good case to test some of my own limits as a coder as well as gain deeper understanding of the tools available to me. The example code you linked to brings a lot into focus.